# Ajax PUT retornando erro 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, front-end

Fiz um ajax para usar o metodo PUT para dar update no campo de uma tabela mas o servidor (rest) está me retornando erro 500 e eu não sei o que estou fazendo errado, alguem pode me dar uma luz porfavor?

Erro que da: OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
$(document).on('click', "#modalgravar", function(){
        var eUrl = "http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/"; 
        var Ecdgrupo = $("#Cdgrupoedit").val();
        var Egrupo = $("#grupoedit").val();
        var eData ={Cdgrupo: Ecdgrupo, Grupos: Egrupo};


        $.ajax({type:"put",

                url: eUrl,
                    data: JSON.stringify(eData),
                contentType: "application/json",


                success: function(){
                    alert("Editado!");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Erro:  O grupo não foi editado!");
                }
            }); 
    });
```

Comment: Qual a  versão do jQuery que vc tá usando?

Comment: Sou bem leigo mas estou usando a jquery-1.12.4.min.js, acredito que seja versão 1.12 certo?

Comment: Acho que você deveria usar PATCH e não PUT, PUT é para quando substitui tudo, PATCH quando substitui parte da informação, ou seja uma atualização. O erro 500 é do servidor então vai precisar do log de lá para saber o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Qual linguagem você esta usando no back-end, o erro está lá, coloca o código do back, talvez não suporte PUT

Comment: @LeonardoBarros Infelizmente eu não tenho acesso ao codigo do back mas eu tenho absoluta certeza de que ele suporta o PUT. Eu acredito que esse erro esteja acontecendo porque o servidor não está reconhecendo a chamada como put e retorna esse erro mas não tenho certeza de nada, e se for isso mesmo não consigo ver aonde estou errando.

Comment: Realmente pode usar PUT. É que na documentação só menciona GET e POST. Mas eu testei aqui e está enviando uma string no formato JSON, tipo: `{"Cdgrupo":"2","Grupos":"5"}`.

Comment: @rnd_rss Cheguei a pensar em usar o patch também mas acredito que o put seria o mais correto pro meu objetivo. Mas posso tentar usar o patch também.

Comment: @Sam O retorno é esse mesmo mas isso acontece apenas na tela comigo